# Closed form for $\int_0^\infty e^{-x}\sin^a(x)dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Can we find a closed form for $$I(a)=\int_0^\infty e^{-x}\sin^a(x)dx$$
Mathematica can easily find closed form for integer $a$:

\begin{align*}
I(0)&=1\\
I(1)&=1/2\\
I(2)&=2/5\\
I(3)&=3/10\\
I(4)&=24/85\\
I(5)&=3/13\\
I(6)&=144/629\\
I(7)&=63/325\\
\end{align*}

Comment: What have you tired?
Any ideas?

Comment: It has a hypergeometric indefinite integral.

Comment: Start by writing $\sin(x)^a$ = $\frac{1}{(2i)^a}(e^{ix}-e^{-ix})^a$ and use the binomial theorem. switch summation and integration. The  Integrals are now trivial and the resulting sum seems to be treatable.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps this should be a comment instead of an answer, but...

I don't know if we can find a closed form expression using standard functions (maybe if we allow the gamma function?), but we can certainly define a recurrence relation.

After integrating this by parts *twice*, we get:

$$\int e^{-x}\sin^{a}(x)dx = \frac{e^{-x}sin^{(a-1)}(x)}{1+a^2} + \frac{a(a-1)}{a^2+1}\int e^{-x}\sin^{a-2}(x)dx$$

When we make it definite, the first term goes away entirely:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x}\sin^{a}(x)dx = \frac{a(a-1)}{a^2+1}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x}\sin^{a-2}(x)dx$$

From here, a recurrence relation becomes obvious:

$$I(a) = \frac{a(a-1)}{a^2+1}I(a-2)$$

This isn't closed form, but it's a start... might be useful for further analysis.

Answer (score 3):

This a partial answer, in case of $a$ integer.

$I(a)$ is the Laplace transform of $\sin^a(x)$ for the particular value $s=1$
$$L_x[\sin^{a}(x)](s)=\int_0^\infty\sin^a(x)e^{-sx}dx$$
The tables of Laplace Transforms  gives:
$$L_x[\sin^{2n}(x)](s)=\frac{(2n)!}{s(s^2+2^2)(s^2+4^2)(s^2+6^2)...(s^2+(2n)^2)}$$
$$L_x[\sin^{2n+1}(x)](s)=\frac{(2n+1)!}{(s^2+1^2)(s^2+3^2)(s^2+5^2)...(s^2+(2n+1)^2)}$$
With $s=1$ :
$$\int_0^\infty\sin^{2n}(x)e^{-x}dx=\frac{(2n)!}{(1+2^2)(1+4^2)(1+6^2)...(1+(2n)^2)}$$
$$\int_0^\infty\sin^{2n+1}(x)e^{-x}dx=\frac{(2n+1)!}{(1+1^2)(1+3^2)(1+5^2)...(1+(2n+1)^2)}$$
From H.Bateman, "Tables of Integral Transforms", Eq.(3) & (7),p .150 , McGraw Hill, 1954.

In case of $a$ real, the closed form involves the Gauss hypergeometric function : http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+sin%28x%29%5Eaexp%28-x%29dx+

Comment: Out of curiosity, how would you integrate from $0$ to $\infty$ for real $a$?