# Integrating $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin^n (ax)}{x^n \cdot (x^2+1)} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I was trying to evaluate an expression for the family of integrals

$$ I(a,n) = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin^n(ax)}{x^n(x^2+1)} dx$$

For positive $a$ and $n$

The expression for the first few $n$ can be computed by hand. For example, for the case when $n=1$ we have:

$$ I(a,1) = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin(ax)}{x(x^2+1)} dx$$

Differentiating, we get:

$$ I'(a,1) = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\cos(ax)}{x^2+1} dx = \frac{\pi}{2}\cdot e^{-a}$$

Since $I(0,1) = 0$, we can write $I(a,1)$ as:

$$ I(a,1) = \frac{\pi}{2} \cdot (1-e^{-a})$$

For $n=2$, we again differentiate with respect to $a$. We get:

$$I'(a,2) = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin(2ax)}{x(x^2+1)} dx = I(2a,1) = \frac{\pi}{2} \cdot (1-e^{-2a})$$

Again observing that $I(0,2) = 0$, we can write $I(a,2)$ as:

$$I(a,2) = \frac{\pi}{2} \cdot (a + \frac{1}{2}\cdot e^{-2a} - \frac{1}{2})$$

With some rather tedious effort in computing the third derivative, we can use the same strategy to evaluate $I(a,3)$. I obtained:

$$I(a,3) = \frac{\pi}{8} \cdot (3a^2+ 3e^{-a} -e^{-3a}-2)$$

I hypothesize after looking at the pattern that the expression for $I(a,n)$ must be some fraction of $\pi$, multiplied by the sum of a polynomial of degree $n-1$ added to some exponentials of the form $e^{-ka}$ where $k$ ranges from $1$ to $n$.

But I was wondering if we can afford to keep doing this for higher and higher values of $n$. I don't have a surefire way of obtaining an expression for general $n$, except for repeated differentiation, simplification and reverse integration.

Can anyone help me in evaluating an expression that holds for all natural $n$?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you for reading!

Comment: Probably the residue theorem is of use, as with the case for $I(a, 1).$

Comment: You should probably mention you assume $a\ge0$, since otherwise $I(a,\,1)=\frac12\pi(1-e^{-|a|})$ etc.

Comment: @J.G. Oh yes, thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @SeanRoberson But I don't know how to do contour integration. Is a solution impossible via real analytical methods?

Comment: I don't know of any purely real methods off the bat, but another suggestion is the Fourier transform and just take real and imaginary parts.

Comment: I may be wrong but I do not get the same results. $$I(a,2)=\frac{1}{4} \pi  \left(2 a+e^{-2 a}-1\right)$$ $$I(a,3)=-\frac{1}{8} \pi  \left(-3 a^2+e^{-3 a}-3 e^{-a}+2\right)$$ It does not look to be an easy problem at all.

Comment: My bad, your $I(a,2)$ looks correct. I missed the  $\frac{-1}{2}$.  About $I(a,3)$ - that too seems correct. I messed up badly.

Comment: @ТymaGaidash Sure!

Comment: very nice question ...........+1

Comment: One idea is taking Laplace transform, like [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2950772/using-laplace-transforms-to-evaluate-int-0-infty-frac-sin2xx2x2?noredirect=1), [integrating](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1029753/closed-form-for-int-0-infty-e-x-sinaxdx/1029847#1029847), applying partial fractions to get a finite sum, and applying the inverse transform to get the closed form for $n\in\Bbb N$. However, this is fairly tedious.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that
$$
\begin{aligned}
I(a,n)
&=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin^n(ax)}{x^n(1+x^2)}\\
&=\frac{a^n}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\left(\frac{\sin(ax)}{ax}\right)^n\frac{dx}{1+x^2}\\
&=\frac{a^n}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\left(\frac{\sin(ax)}{ax}\right)^n\frac{e^{-2\pi i \xi x}}{1+x^2}dx\Biggl|_{\xi=0}\\
&=\frac{a^n}{2}\mathcal{F}\left[\left(\frac{\sin(ax)}{ax}\right)^n\frac{1}{1+x^2}\right](\xi)\Biggl|_{\xi=0}
\end{aligned}
$$
where by $\mathcal{F}$ we denote the Fourier transform
$$
\mathcal{F}[f(x)](\xi)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)e^{-2\pi i \xi x}dx
$$
Recall that
$$
\mathcal{F}\left[\frac{1}{1+x^2}\right](\xi)
=\pi e^{-2\pi|\xi|},
\quad\quad
\mathcal{F}\left[\frac{\sin(\pi k x)}{\pi k x}\right](\xi)=\frac{1}{|k|}\operatorname{rect}\left(\frac{\xi}{k}\right)
$$
where
$$
\operatorname{rect}(x)
=\frac{1}{2}\left(
\operatorname{sign}\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)
-
\operatorname{sign}\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)
\right).
$$
It is well known that $\mathcal{F}[f(x)\cdot g(x)](\xi)=\mathcal{F}[f(x)](\xi)*\mathcal{F}[g(x)](\xi)$, so for $a> 0$ we get
$$
\begin{aligned}
I(a, n)
&=\frac{a^n}{2}\cdot\mathcal{F}\left[\left(\prod\limits_{i=1}^{n}\frac{\sin(ax)}{ax}\right)\cdot\frac{1}{1+x^2}\right](\xi)\Biggl|_{\xi=0}\\
&=\frac{a^n}{2}\cdot\left(\ast_{i=1}^n\mathcal{F}\left[\frac{\sin(ax)}{ax}\right](\xi)\right)*\mathcal{F}\left[\cdot\frac{1}{1+x^2}\right](\xi)\Biggl|_{\xi=0}\\
&=\frac{a^n}{2}\cdot\left(\ast_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{|a/\pi|}\operatorname{rect}\left(\frac{\xi}{a/\pi}\right)\right)*\pi e^{-2\pi |\xi|}\Biggl|_{\xi=0}\\
&=\frac{a^n\pi^{n+1}}{2a^n}\cdot\left(\ast_{i=1}^n\operatorname{rect}\left(\frac{\pi\xi}{a}\right)\right)* e^{-2\pi |\xi|}\Biggl|_{\xi=0}\\
&=\frac{\pi^{n+1}}{2}\int\limits_{
\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n+1}s_i=\xi}\prod_{i=1}^n\operatorname{rect}\left(\frac{\pi s_i}{a}\right)\cdot e^{-2\pi |s_{n+1}|} d\sigma\Biggl|_{\xi=0}\\
&=\frac{\pi^{n+1}}{2}\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^n}\prod_{i=1}^n\operatorname{rect}\left(\frac{\pi s_i}{a}\right)\cdot e^{-2\pi \left|\xi-\sum\limits_{i=1}^ns_{i}\right|} ds\Biggl|_{\xi=0}\\
&=\frac{\pi^{n+1}}{2}\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^n}\prod_{i=1}^n\operatorname{rect}\left(\frac{\pi s_i}{a}\right)\cdot e^{-2\pi \left|\sum\limits_{i=1}^ns_{i}\right|} ds\\
&=\left\{t_i=2\pi s_i,i\in\mathbb{N}_n\right\}\\
&=\frac{\pi^{n+1}}{2}\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^n}\prod_{i=1}^n\operatorname{rect}\left(\frac{t_i}{2a}\right)\cdot e^{-\left|\sum\limits_{i=1}^n t_{i}\right|} \frac{1}{(2\pi)^n} dt\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2^{n+1}}\int\limits_{\left[-a,a\right]^n} e^{- \left|\sum\limits_{i=1}^n t_{i}\right|} dt\\
\end{aligned}
$$
The last integral is doable I believe. At least for $n=2$ it gives the same result as yours. If I have time I'll try to give an explicit formula for it.

Comment: Thanks for showing every step involved, I did not know how to do Fourier Transforms, but I was able to follow through your solution! Grateful for that.

Comment: Please have a look at the paper [Slices, Slabs, and Sections of the Unit Hypercube by Jean-Luc Marichal and Michael J. Mossinghof](https://hosted.math.rochester.edu/ojac/vol3/Marichal_2008.pdf). I think with some effort one can arrive at explicit formula as a finite sum